# Regex para quitar caracteres que no sean del español, pero que mantenga tildes y otros símbolos

Tags: c#, regex

Necesito una expresión regular para eliminar los caracteres especiales, pero que mantenga sin quitar letras, números, vocales con tildes y otros símbolos.

Lo que necesito es que deje todos los caracteres permitidos en español, incluyendo letras, números, tildes, puntos y comas, paréntesis, etc; y eliminar caracteres especiales por ejemplo emojis, y ese tipo de símbolos que no son del idioma español.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
string s = "søme string";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+ á,é,í,ó,ú", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Sigue el [tour] y revisa [ask].

Comment: @inec Tal cual se pide en https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info, deberías incluir más información en tu pregunta. Faltarían ejemplos, resultados esperados y casos que no deban coincidir. Actualmente, no queda del todo claro qué caracteres específicos se desean eliminar (o en su defecto dejar), y decir "los permitidos en español" es un poco amplio y deja lugar a interpretaciones. En caso de que sea sólo el rango U+0000 a U+007F más vocales con tildes (como se muestra en tu código, deberías especificarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Actualmente en tu código estás intentando definir que coincida con todos los caracteres por fuera del rango U+0000 a U+007F. Para agregar más caracteres, sólo se deben incorporar en la [clase de caracteres negada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#mt68):

```
[^\u0000-\u007FáéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ¿¡]+
```

O, lo que es lo mismo, con la opción [IgnoreCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[^\p{IsBasicLatin}áéíóúüñ¿¡]+
```

Y, sobre esta clase, se puede agregar cualquier caracter que desees incluir.

---

**Ejemplo**

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
string[] pruebas = { "søme string", "letras 12345 áéíóúüñ", "LETRAS 12345 ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ", 
                    "[*(¿¡p.r'u_e-ba!?)],", "emojis ➡️✔ #etc.️",
                    "a\"b\"c", "Barça $%&/()*¨;:_"};

foreach (string texto in pruebas)
{
    string resultado = Regex.Replace(texto, @"[^\p{IsBasicLatin}áéíóúüñ¿¡]+", string.Empty, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("{0,25} => {1}", texto, resultado);
}
```

**Salida**

```
              søme string => sme string
     letras 12345 áéíóúüñ => letras 12345 áéíóúüñ
     LETRAS 12345 ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ => LETRAS 12345 ÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ
     [*(¿¡p.r'u_e-ba!?)], => [*(¿¡p.r'u_e-ba!?)],
emojis ➡️✔ #etc.️ => emojis  #etc.
                    a"b"c => a"b"c
        Barça $%&/()*¨;:_ => Bara $%&/()*;:_
```

**Demo**

http://ideone.com/7JkNxQ

Comment: Hola @mariano, gracias por respuesta, lo que necesito es que deje todos los caracteres permitidos en español, incluyendo letras, números, tildes, puntos y comas, paréntesis etc... Y eliminar caracteres especiales por ejemplo emojis, y ese tipo de símbolos que no son del idioma español.

Comment: En ese caso, deberías editar tu pregunta aclarando qué caracteres específicos se deben incluir, o cuáles son los caracteres específicos que se desea eliminar, mostrando ejemplos y resultados esperados